# Relacion @ManyToOne en una @MappedSuperclass

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, patron-dto, anotaciones

Estoy comenzando a utilizar las anotaciones JPA en spring boot y me topé con la siguiente cuestion:
Tengo una superclase llamada **Persona** de la cual heredan (por ahora) dos clases: la clase **Asistencial** y la clase **NoAsistencial** (y seguramente tendre que agregar tres clases heredadas más). Estas dos clases deben relacionarse con la clase **NovedadPersonal** en una relacion **1 a N**. Lo que necesito es poner esa relacion en la superclase, pero que a la vez en el mapeo de la base de datos, no aparezca la tabla **Persona**, solo las tablas **asistencial** y **no_asistencial**. Los codigos son los siguientes:

**Clase Peresona**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)")
    private String apellido;
    private int dni;
    private String cuil;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "novedadesPersonales")
    private Set<NovedadPersonal> novedadesPersonales;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "suplente")
    private Set<NovedadPersonal> suplente;

}
```

Las clases **Asistencial** y **NoAsistencial** varian en un par de atributos, solo pongo **Asistencial** a modo de ejmplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asistenciales")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Asistencial extends Person {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(15)")
    private String sexo;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(15)")
    private String telefono;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(15)")
    private String email;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(25)")
    private String domicilio;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT true")
    private Boolean estado;

}
```

Y por ultimo la clasee **NovedadPersonal** que es la clase con la cual deben relacionarse

```
public class NovedadPersonal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaInicio;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate fechaFinal;
    private boolean puedeRealizarGuardia;
    private boolean cobraSueldo;
    private boolean necesitaReemplazo;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(80)")
    private String descripcion;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_novedadesPersonales")
    private Person novedadesPersonales;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_suplente")
    private Person suplente;

}
```

Todas las clases tienen las importaciones necesarias y stoy utilizando el patron de diseño DTO, por lo cual, cada una de las eentidades tiene su repositorio, servicio, clase Dto y Controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que necesitas usar la anotación @AssociationOverride:

```java
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class Person {
        ...
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "novedadesPersonales")
        private Set<NovedadPersonal> novedadesPersonales;
        ...
    }
    
    @Entity 
    @AssociationOverride(name="novedadesPersonales")        
    public class Asistencial extends Person {
        ...
    }
```

Puedes mirar más detalles en la [documentación de la API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/index.html?javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)